# Most common use cases for in order traversal, pre order travsersal and post order traversal

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I know the definitions of :

1. Pre order travesral
2. In order traversal
3. Post order traversal

But I would like to know what are the most common uses cases of all the above three different types of traversal for a BST(Binary search tree) .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Postorder Traversal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216206/postorder-traversal)

Comment: [good explanation](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/618)

Comment: A bad close, methinks.  This entry is the first google result for "best use cases for X", where X is any of the traversal tactics requested above.  Having had a succinct answer here true to SO form would have been productive.